# Excel vba to create every possible combination of a Range

Tags: excel, permutation, combinations, static-methods, vba

I have a problem that I haven't been able to find anywhere on the web (it may be there, but I can't find it, heh).

I have a spreadsheet with 13 columns of data.  Each of the column contains variations of a parameter that needs to go into an overall test case.

All of them differ, like

E:
101%
105%
110%
120%

J:
Upper S
Upside L
Downside B
Premium V

I have seen several solutions to the combination issue which uses nested loops.  I'd like to steer clear of 13 nested loops (but this is my best bet at the moment).  I'm kind of at a loss on how to generate every unique combination in in each column.

I'm not sure if that makes enough sense for you guys. I was hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction with a recursive algorithm.  I'd like to make it dynamic enough to take varying numbers of columns and rows.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: I am afraid, you will have to use loops. The best would be to use 13 arrays and each array holds the particular range and then generate the combinations.

Comment: The best method I have come across is to set up an ODBC data connection that points the Excel file at itself, then create a cross join (Cartesian) query against your data.

Comment: OK, "best" may not have been a good choice of words. Another way is to set up a worksheet that iterates all possible indices, then use `INDEX` to look up the values. This is, in effect, a 13-dimension array, but using only worksheet functions.

Comment: I like that cross join solution.  I will have to give it a shot tomorrow.  I didn't even think of that.

Comment: if you want a "vba only" answer that scales to any number of "sets" (aka dimensions or categories) and any number of members per set, see my answer below.

Comment: My solution below handles an arbitrary number of columns of arbitrary lengths, nothing hard-coded

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since I offered an ODBC approach I thought I should elaborate on it, as it is not immediately obvious how to do this. And, in honesty, I needed to relearn the process and document it for myself.

This is a way to generate a [Cartesian product](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A%20cartesian%20product&oq=define%3A%20cartesian%20product) of two or more one-dimensional data arrays using Excel and Microsoft Query.

These instructions were written with XL2007 but should work with minor (if any) modifications in any version.

### Step 1

Organize the arrays in columns.

*Important:* Each column should have two "header" names as shown in bold below. The topmost name will later be interpreted as a "table name". The second name will be interpreted as a "column name". This will become apparent a few steps later.

Select each data range in turn, including both "headers", and hit `Ctrl+Shift+F3`. Tick only `Top row` in the 'Create Names" dialog and click `OK`.

Once all named ranges are established, save the file.

[image]

### Step 2

Data | Get External Data | From Other Sources | From Microsoft Query

Choose `<New Data Source>`. In the `Choose New Data Source` dialog:

1. A friendly name for your connection
2. choose the appropriate Microsoft Excel driver

... then `Connect`

[image]

### Step 3

`Select Workbook...` then browse for your file.

[image]

### Step 4

Add the "columns" from your "tables". You can see now why the "two header" layout in step 1 is important--it tricks the driver into understanding the data correctly.

Next click `Cancel` (really!). You might be prompted at this point to "continue editing in Microsoft Query?" (answer `Yes`), or a complaint that joins cannot be represented in the graphical editor. Ignore this and forge on...

[image]

### Step 5

Microsoft Query opens, and by default the tables you added will be cross-joined. This will generate a Cartesian product, which is what we want.

Now close MSQuery altogether.

[image]

### Step 6

You are returned to the worksheet. Almost done, I promise! Tick `New worksheet` and `OK`.

[image]

### Step 7

The cross-joined results are returned.

[image]

Comment: Good! Alternatively, and my usual way of doing this, is to copy the columns into tables in MS Access and generating these results in there the same way. Then it can be easily copied back to Excel.

Comment: +1 from me too. I wish i could give like +3 or something, for the effort and clear explanation

Comment: really really really cool! ive used excel for like 15 years and didnt know about this

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why you are averse to looping. See this example. It took less than a second.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Range("G2").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 6

    For i = 1 To 4: For j = 1 To 4
    For k = 1 To 8: For l = 1 To 12
        Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("B" & j).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("C" & k).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("D" & l).Value
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
    Next: Next
    Next: Next

    Range("G1").Value = CountComb
    Range("G3").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**NOTE**: The above was a small example. I did a test on 4 columns with with 200 rows each. The total combination possible in such a scenario is `1600000000` and it took 16 seconds.

In such a case it crosses the Excel rows limit. One other option that I can think of is writing the output to a text file in such a scenario. If your data is small then you can get away without using arrays and directly writing to the cells. :) But in case of large data, I would recommend using arrays.

Comment: Hi Siddharth,  Thanks for the response.  One of the problems I'm facing is the number of input columns can, and will, vary.  Sometimes its 13, sometimes 6, sometimes 12.  I can always tweak it, but I am looking for something that isn't a one-off.  I appreciate your example, and is definitely helping me move in the right direction though.

Comment: You can always use `ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to find the last column :)

Answer (score 6):

I needed this myself several times and finally built it.

I believe the code scales for any total number of columns and any number of distinct values within columns (e.g. each column can contain any number of values)

It assumes all values in each column are unique (if this is not true, you will get duplicate rows)

It assumes you want to cross-join output based on whatever cells you have currently selected (make sure you select them all)

It assumes you want the output to start one column after the current selection.

How it works (briefly):
first for each column and for each row: It calculates the number of total rows needed to support all combos in N columns (items in column 1 * items in column 2 ... * items in column N)

second for each column: Based on the total combos, and the total combos of the previous columns it calculates two loops.

ValueCycles (how many times you have to cycle through all the values in the current column)
ValueRepeats (how many times to repeat each value in the column consecutively)

```
Sub sub_CrossJoin()

Dim rg_Selection As Range
Dim rg_Col As Range
Dim rg_Row As Range
Dim rg_Cell As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCol As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCell As Range
Dim int_PriorCombos As Long
Dim int_TotalCombos As Long
Dim int_ValueRowCount As Long
Dim int_ValueRepeats As Long
Dim int_ValueRepeater As Long
Dim int_ValueCycles As Long
Dim int_ValueCycler As Long

int_TotalCombos = 1
int_PriorCombos = 1
int_ValueRowCount = 0
int_ValueCycler = 0
int_ValueRepeater = 0

Set rg_Selection = Selection
Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_Selection.Cells(1, 1)
Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, rg_Selection.Columns.Count)

'get total combos
For Each rg_Col In rg_Selection.Columns
    int_ValueRowCount = 0
    For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
        If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        int_ValueRowCount = int_ValueRowCount + 1
    Next rg_Row
    int_TotalCombos = int_TotalCombos * int_ValueRowCount
Next rg_Col

int_ValueRowCount = 0

'for each column, calculate the repeats needed for each row value and then populate the destination
For Each rg_Col In rg_Selection.Columns
    int_ValueRowCount = 0
    For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
        If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        int_ValueRowCount = int_ValueRowCount + 1
    Next rg_Row
    int_PriorCombos = int_PriorCombos * int_ValueRowCount
    int_ValueRepeats = int_TotalCombos / int_PriorCombos


    int_ValueCycles = (int_TotalCombos / int_ValueRepeats) / int_ValueRowCount
    int_ValueCycler = 0

    int_ValueRepeater = 0

    Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCol

    For int_ValueCycler = 1 To int_ValueCycles
        For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
            If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

                For int_ValueRepeater = 1 To int_ValueRepeats
                    rg_DestinationCell.Value = rg_Row.Value
                    Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCell.Offset(1, 0)
                Next int_ValueRepeater

        Next rg_Row
    Next int_ValueCycler

    Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, 1)
Next rg_Col
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution based on my second comment. This example assumes you have three columns of data but can be adapted to handle more.

I start with your sample data. I added counts on the top row for convenience. I also added the total number of combinations (product of the counts). This is `Sheet1`:

[image]

On `Sheet2`:

[image]

Formulae:

`A2:C2` (orange cells) are hard coded `=0`

```
A3=IF(SUM(B3:C3)=0,MOD(A2+1,Sheet1!$E$1),A2)

B3=IF(C3=0,MOD(B2+1,Sheet1!$G$1),B2)

C3=MOD(C2+1,Sheet1!$J$1)

D2=INDEX(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$5,Sheet2!A2+1)

E2=INDEX(Sheet1!$G$2:$G$6,Sheet2!B2+1)

F2=INDEX(Sheet1!$J$2:$J$5,Sheet2!C2+1)
```

Fill from row 3 down as many rows as `Total` shows on `Sheet1`

Comment: Your solution may be easier to adapt to a varying number of columns, but I'm not fond of relative solutions (in which each row is determined as a function of the preceding row) when not necessary.  You can compute `A`, `B`, and `C` with absolute formulas: `A2` `=INT((ROW()-2)/($G$1*$J$1))`, `B2` `=MOD(INT((ROW()-2)/$J$1), $G$1)`, and `C2` `=MOD((ROW()-2), $J$1)`. FWIW, your formulas will wrap after 80 (4×5×4) rows, while mine will allow Column `A` to grow without bound; of course, that's trivial to fix.

Answer (score 0):

call the method and put into the current level, which will be decremented in the method (sorry for eng)

sample:

```
    sub MyAdd(i as integer)
      if i > 1 then
        MyAdd = i + MyAdd(i-1)
      else
        MyAdd = 1
      end if
    end sub
```