# Get value of one column based on value of two OTHER columns, then change column on another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a workbook with three worksheets. I need to change the value in column K(row) on workbook B with the value of column CF(row) from workbook A based on a criteria (index?) of columns A and C on Workbook A and columns B and D on worksheet B. That is, these worksheets have the data in a DIFFERENT ORDER, one cannot simply loop through and copy over. I need to find the Row number of the CF(row) in worksheet A where the worksheet A and C columns are the same as the worksheet A B and D columns.

PsuedoSQL

```sql
UPDATE 
    Worksheet B
SET
    Worksheet B.K = Worksheet A.CF
FROM
    Worksheet A
WHERE
    Worksheet A.B = Worksheet B.B
```

Select from Worksheet A, column CF WHERE A.A AND A.C is equal to worksheet B.B and B.D AND SET Worksheet B.K(Row) to Value worksheetA.CF(row)

The code I have is a look up that finds the LAST column with the matching text on worksheet A Column A, without any index or mapping.

```
Public Function FindPnum(keyword As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim tRow As Long
    Dim tCol As Integer

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find(keyword, ws.[b2], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = ws.Cells.Find(keyword, ws.[b2], xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        FindPnum = Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column).Address(0, 0)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: So let me try and disect what you want. If column A and C in worksheet A are equal to column B and D in worksheet B then set column K in worksheet B equal to column CK in worksheet A?

Comment: @AxGryndr Well, since you put it so eloquently... that is what I mean, however not exactly. The data on the sheets is not in the same order, so I presume a search function will be needed in order to loop through  Worksheet B and find the matching row in Worksheet A, and return THAT row CF value, to populate Worksheet B's K value (not the same row id as CF row id)

Comment: Ok are we talk about one instance on sheet A and one instance on sheet B?

Comment: @AxGryndr Not sure what you mean. There are multiples of Worksheet A.A and Worksheet B.B, which is why I was thinking/planning on using worksheet A.C and worksheet B.D in conjuction, to come up with the unique selection of CF. With those two columns acting as an index, there would only be ONE matching row though, yes.

Comment: Right so the pair of A,C is only going to match one pair of B,D.

Comment: @AxGryndr To the best of my knowledge, yes. However, no clue how to do that in VBA and thus my above plea!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16114/discussion-between-penguincoder-and-axgryndr)

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: Are you farmiliar with SQL? Is SQL more comfortable for you? If so... read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range it will provide details that should get you toward an SQl solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

```
Sub pair()
Dim r, r2, found
r = 8
r2 = 2
found = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(2).Activate
Do Until Len(Cells(r, 2).Value) = 0
Do Until Len(Sheets(1).Cells(r2 + 1, 2).Value) = 0 Or found = True
    If Sheets(2).Cells(r, 2).Text = Sheets(1).Cells(r2, 2).Text Then
        If Sheets(2).Cells(r, 11).Value <> 0 Then
            Sheets(2).Cells(r, 11).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(r2, 84)
        End If
        found = True
    Else
        r2 = r2 + 1
    End If
Loop
r2 = 2
r = r + 1
found = False
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think this should do it.

Comment: @AxGrynder Thanks for all your help. I ended up going with your last suggestion in chat - a vlookup:  `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B21151,'Sheet 1'!B:CF,83,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(B21151,'Sheet 1'!B:CF,83,FALSE))` then just carried it through to all the other cells in that column. Works for now!

Comment: @PenguinCoder You can change the If(Isna()) for Iferror(). Small statement and easier to debug.