# 10 values in column A, 4 in column B, 40 unique outputs?

Tags: excel, formulas

I have been working for a while trying to get 40 unique outputs. I have taken a screenshot of what I'm basically trying to get at.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot from Excel]

I have been using `INDIRECT` and `CEILING` commands but can not get anything to work. 
Can someone please please help and explain?

Comment: What you want is a Cartesian product. I offer one solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10694508/1248931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
="the brown " & INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW()/4,1)) & " jumped over the "& INDEX(B:B,(MOD(ROW()-1,4)+1))
```

It uses `CEILING` along with division by four to repeat each item in column A 4 times. It uses `MOD` to cycle through the four numbers.

You can generalize it to work with however many values are in column B by using `COUNTA`:

```
="the brown " & INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW()/COUNTA(B:B),1)) & " jumped over the "& INDEX(B:B,(MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way of doing this with formulas. Try this vba for starters:

```
Dim listA As Range
Dim listB As Range

Set listA = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set listB = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))

y = 1

For Each cellA In listA
    For Each cellB In listB
        Cells(y, 4).Value = "blah " & cellA.Value & ", blah " & cellB.Value
        y = y + 1
    Next
Next
```

This assumes your first list of variables is in column A starting on row 1, with no gaps, and that your second list of variables is in column B starting on row 1, with no gaps. It loops through all values in these ranges - an outer loop for column A values and an inner loop for column B values. Each unique combination is entered into column D starting on row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting to see if I could figure out a formula... eventually I gave up, and found [this solution](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654871-how-generate-all-possible-combinations-two-lists-without-macro.html) on MrExcel, courtesy of **Tusharm**. His post is the third down; he says to paste this into F1 and copy down until you get blank results.

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1))&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```

Comment: This works when I set the range like, =IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A1:A10)*COUNTA(B1:B4),"",INDEX(A1:A10,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COUNTA(B1:B4)+1))&INDEX(B1:B4,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B1:B4))+1)). But how can I add characters in between the two values ("the brown" before, "jumped over the" after)?