# Modifying Excel vba that creates all possible combinations from multiple lists

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, permutation

Hello I found some really great code from a couple years ago to create all possible combinations from multiple rows. It works great but as you try it with more data it returns a run time error 6 overflow. I am very new to VBA but am hoping that there is a way to split up or slow the process down to keep the macro running. My current data should produce 442,368 unique rows, which is a lot but well within the scope of excel's power. I will paste the vba code below. When you hit debug following the error it highlights this row:     **int_TotalCombos = int_TotalCombos * int_ValueRowCount**
I really would appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thank you!

```
Sub sub_CrossJoin()

Dim rg_Selection As Range
Dim rg_Col As Range
Dim rg_Row As Range
Dim rg_Cell As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCol As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCell As Range
Dim int_PriorCombos As Integer
Dim int_TotalCombos As Integer
Dim int_ValueRowCount As Integer
Dim int_ValueRepeats As Integer
Dim int_ValueRepeater As Integer
Dim int_ValueCycles As Integer
Dim int_ValueCycler As Integer

int_TotalCombos = 1
int_PriorCombos = 1
int_ValueRowCount = 0
int_ValueCycler = 0
int_ValueRepeater = 0

Set rg_Selection = Selection
Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_Selection.Cells(1, 1)
Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, rg_Selection.Columns.Count)

'get total combos
For Each rg_Col In rg_Selection.Columns
    int_ValueRowCount = 0
    For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
        If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        int_ValueRowCount = int_ValueRowCount + 1
    Next rg_Row
    int_TotalCombos = int_TotalCombos * int_ValueRowCount
Next rg_Col

int_ValueRowCount = 0

'for each column, calculate the repeats needed for each row value and then populate the destination
For Each rg_Col In rg_Selection.Columns
    int_ValueRowCount = 0
    For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
        If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        int_ValueRowCount = int_ValueRowCount + 1
    Next rg_Row
    int_PriorCombos = int_PriorCombos * int_ValueRowCount
    int_ValueRepeats = int_TotalCombos / int_PriorCombos


    int_ValueCycles = (int_TotalCombos / int_ValueRepeats) / int_ValueRowCount
    int_ValueCycler = 0

    int_ValueRepeater = 0

    Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCol

    For int_ValueCycler = 1 To int_ValueCycles
        For Each rg_Row In rg_Col.Cells
            If rg_Row.Value = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If

                For int_ValueRepeater = 1 To int_ValueRepeats
                    rg_DestinationCell.Value = rg_Row.Value
                    Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCell.Offset(1, 0)
                Next int_ValueRepeater

        Next rg_Row
    Next int_ValueCycler

    Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, 1)
Next rg_Col
End Sub
```

Here is a link to where i found it. See the response by 'Spioter'
[Excel vba to create every possible combination of a Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range)

Spioter also provided the following information:

"I believe the code scales for any total number of columns and any number of distinct values within columns (e.g. each column can contain any number of values)

It assumes all values in each column are unique (if this is not true, you will get duplicate rows)

It assumes you want to cross-join output based on whatever cells you have currently selected (make sure you select them all)

It assumes you want the output to start one column after the current selection.

How it works (briefly): first for each column and for each row: It calculates the number of total rows needed to support all combos in N columns (items in column 1 * items in column 2 ... * items in column N)

second for each column: Based on the total combos, and the total combos of the previous columns it calculates two loops.

ValueCycles (how many times you have to cycle through all the values in the current column) ValueRepeats (how many times to repeat each value in the column consecutively) "

Comment: "Overflow" generally means you've exceeded the size of a variable, so maybe you have too many rows, columns, etc. As a test, I'd change all your `Integer` variables to `Long` and run it again to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I wrote the code , glad it's useful, but it was meant for cases where sql  over head was not desired, for the number of records you are dealing with a sql cross join will be 1000x more efficient

Comment: Please upvote my original post if you found this code useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Integer declarations to data type Long.  Integer has a limit of around 32,000.  Long goes past 2 billion.

```
Dim int_PriorCombos As Long
Dim int_TotalCombos As Long
Dim int_ValueRowCount As Long
' and so on for the other integers
```

You'll probably want to rename them throughout the code, so the name matches the data type:

```
Dim lng_PriorCombos As Long
Dim lng_TotalCombos As Long
Dim lng_ValueRowCount As Long
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This fixed the Overflow error message but now when I run the macro it hangs and Excel becomes non responsive. When I go to exit Excel it shows a new error " Method 'Value' of object 'Range' Failed  "
This occurs on this line:                      rg_DestinationCell.Value = rg_Row.Value

Comment: Update: I ran it again and just didnt touch the screen for a while and even though it took a while it did eventually work. Thank you for your help. Is there any way to make it less taxing on the computer because if you even click on the spreadsheet it becomes non responding and that's when the macro fails. Maybe there is no solution and producing 400,000 plus rows from this macro is just too much for excel to handle.

Comment: Creating over 400,000 rows is a big task. It's especially slow if the Sub outputs each cell one at a time. It will work a lot quicker if you change the code so the data goes into an array first, and then you output that array all at once, but that would take a lot of extra programming.

Comment: BTW, since my answer helped you, it would be nice if you marked it as "the answer". ;-)

Comment: To BrettFromLA: the code is designed to provide equivalent of a sql cross join and dynamically handle an arbitrary number of columns each with an arbitrary number of rows. I am a self taught vba hacker so it very well could be improved, I would be interested to see a more efficient way , especially one that uses arrays but  still supports dynamic numbers of columns/rows

Comment: I think the pseudocode would be something like this:  (1) Find the dimensions of the range.  (2) Pull that into a 2-dimensional array, which you can resize as needed using Redim Preserve. (3) Do all the steps from the loops in your current code, but do them to the data in the array. (4) Use Redim Preserve along the way to grow the array as needed. (5) Dump the array back into your worksheet.  To convert ranges to arrays and dump arrays back into ranges, I read this - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx . (I'm a self-taught VBA hacker too!)

Comment: i don't think you can ReDim an array using a variable - e.g. you can't do this
Dim MyArray As Variant
desired_array_dimensions = "(10, 15, 20)"
redim MyArray desired_array_dimensions

Also, if your results end up in a DB anyway, make sure you know how to do a "cross join" in SQL - this will be much faster.