# Create pairs from values in a column based on values of another column in excel?

Tags: excel

So I need to create two columns which contain every possible pair of Xs of every different Z (including the ones that have a single X value) in excel.

Is there any way I can achieve that (like my in my screenshot)? Bear in mind that my dataset has 1000s of rows.

[image: How can I go create pairs for every Z that has many different X values?]

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why is the pair (2,3) not considered for "a"?

Comment: oh I am really sorry... I just forgot to type it... It should be there!

Comment: I don't think this an Excel question. You are not having an issue related about Excel. Your question is about combinatoric and permutations. Is more Maths than Excel. First, try to set up a math solution and then maybe somebody will help to translate that to Excel. But before doing it in Excel, you have to know how do it "on your own".

Comment: ***How many* 1000s** of rows?  (If anything, this is a question about Excel's limitations*, when we're talking about an exponential number of rows & columns.)

Comment: 3000-4000 rows mostly, but 80% of Zs have a single X value

Comment: ...just to confirm:  With your example data,"`E`" would require these pairs: `(8,9) (8,10) (8,11) (9,10) (9,11) (10,11)`, correct?

Comment: also, is this a one-time setup in your workbook, or will the list of values change, requiring pairs to be added & removed dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically if possible, I have a lot of datasets 3-4k rows each.

Comment: I will change excel file if that helps you but the set up would be always the same (analysing 2 columns ( Z , X) and creating pairs out of them).

Comment: Yeah! Because it has values 8, 9, 10, and 11. If it has 1 X value no pair, if it has 2 values - 1 pair, 3 values - 3 pairs , 4 values 10 pairs and so on.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a **[Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)**.  There are a few ways that list could be created (either programmatically and with builtin features). Usually on Stack Overflow, you are to show that that you've attempted to solve the problem on before asking, but I'll post an answer with one possible method (in a few minsutes)

Comment: I didn't know this has a name in mathematics.. Thanks you so much for your help!!

Comment: @user523230 For future reference, when posting on Stack Overflow, you should try to word your question as accurately as possible from the start. If your question contains trivial errors (such as forgetting the pair (2,3) for "a", and erroneously adding extra entries for "e"), then users will down-vote your question indicating to other users that the question is very poor quality and that the poster of the question put practically no effort into researching and/or presenting the problem.

Comment: You're welcome -- but I realized the answer I was about to post would combine `all` items from each column (55 combinations) instead of only the ones with "matches".  This is not "*one*" Cartesian Product, it's *three* sets of Cartesian Products for **Z** values with more than 1 match `A, B, E`. -- since you're not looking for `A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, etc…`; and I your full set of responses should be: **A:** `{ (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) }` **B:** `{ (4,5) }`  **E:** `{ (7,8) (7,9) (7,10) (7,11) (8,9) (8,10) (8,11) (9,10) (9,11) (10,11) }`.

Comment: ...I suppose a VBA nested loop would be the easiest way to generate a list like you describe.  Are you comfortable with using VBA if I slap together example code?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try my best! :)

Comment: oh no I have no experience with Basic... I have used a bit of R before though... Do you know R ?

Comment: I was actually trying to do exactly that in R but I couldn't figure it out in the end.. do you want me to send you what I have done? I think that I had it almost solved..

Comment: I haven't used R. But I will answer with the steps I would take (in any language).  ...couple minutes

Answer (score 0):

A list of all possible combinations from two lists is called a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), but I suppose that's not exactly what you need, since you want all [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of values from `X` for each label in `Z`.

Googling "list all combinations in Excel" will show some examples that get you *close* using, for example:

- a [Pivot Table](https://chandoo.org/wp/2016/10/04/generate-all-combinations-from-two-lists-excel/), or,
- an [Excel Table with Excel Query](http://www.ashishmathur.com/create-all-possible-combinations-from-different-ranges-without-using-vba/), or,
- [Nested loops in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788986/modifying-excel-vba-that-creates-all-possible-combinations-from-multiple-lists).

Each of those methods will find all combinations, which is what you want to do for each unique value in `Z`.

You could create simple code in your language of choice that does this:

```
create an array that will later hold values from [X]
for each row with data:
    make [currentLabel] = value from [Z]
    append value [X] to the array
    if [currentLabel] does not equal [previousLabel] then:
        {list all combinations in the array}
        (that will be the list for label [currentLabel])
        clear the array
    make [previousLabel] = [currentLabel]
next row
```

As for `{list all combinations in the array}`, that's the easy part:

`[n] in the number of items in the array` and `[n] > 1`

```
for [Counter1] = 1 to [n]
    for [Counter2] = [Counter1}+1 to [n]
        Current combination is: ([Counter1], [Counter2])
    next [Counter2]
next [Counter1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything! I will try to make it work in R! :)

Comment: Great, I hope you get it working! If you're stuck on a specific part of your " [tag:R] " code not behaving as you need it to, you're encouraged to [edit] this question (or ask another one). Make sure to include some/all of your code as applicable (see "[mcve]"), and to include relevant [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), such as perhaps [tag:R] and [tag:cartesian-product]. **Once you get it working** please share your solution for the future benefit of other users! This site can take some getting used to, but there's more good info at "[help]" and also "[ask]" as well as "[help/on-topic]".