# multiple for next loops, 2 (or more) of them must change concurrently

Tags: excel, vba

i have following logic scheme and values:

```
Sub PrezziFissi()

Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, z As Integer
Dim FornitCerca As Range, data As Range, FornitVerif As Range, DataPaste As Range, NomePaste As Range, PrezzoPaste As Range
Dim PrezzoFisso As Range
Dim foglio As Worksheet

Set foglio = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CODICI")

For k = 10 To 110

    Set FornitCerca = foglio.Range("I" & k)
    Set PrezzoFisso = foglio.Range("J" & k)

    For z = 3 To 601
        Set data = foglio.Range("R" & z)
        Set FornitVerif = foglio.Range("S" & z)

        If FornitCerca = FornitVerif Then 'ELABORA - copia e incolla

            For i = 20 To 150

            Set DataPaste = foglio.Range("B" & i)
            Set NomePaste = foglio("C" & i)
            Set PrezzoPaste = foglio("D" & i)

            If PrezzoPaste = 0 Then

            PrezzoFisso.Copy
            PrezzoPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:=xlNone
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            FornitCerca.Copy 'c 20
            NomePaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:=xlNone
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            data.Copy 'b 20
            DataPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, operation:=xlNone
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Else: Next i
            End If
            Next i

        Else: Next z
        End If
        Next z

    Next k


End Sub
```

becuase if only (i) change to forward 1, then it copies values for z=3 in all column D,C and B cells,
if only z change, then in position D20, C20, B20 it overwrites values coming from the matching in row 20

instead i want (i) move forward 1 to another destionation empty cells (Row 21),
 and also matching move from S3 to S4 (below cell to S column)
I wish to put  next z, next I. is it possible? if yes will VBA change that variables concurrently?
thank you so much and apologize for taking your time

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace `Else: Next i` with `Exit For` leaving it inside the `If/End If`. This will take you out of i's `For/Next` loop, increment z and continue on. FWIW, lines like `Else: Next i` should almost *never* be used since `Next i` does the incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Three loops may not be necessary especially because your loop limits are not aligned: z runs longer than k with i much shorter than z. Plus, nested looping will have multiplicative iterations. For instance for each kth element, z will iterate 3 to 150 and then i iterates 20 to 150 for each zth element so overall, 598 * 100 * 130! Almost a [Cartesian Product](https://www.google.com/#q=cartesian+product) effect. This is a reason why you see that overwriting occurring since you iterate constantly over same cells.

**GENERALIZED LOOP**

To iterate concurrently, you can wrap all ranges in a generalized iteration (which you already do), initizialize your iterators and then run your if/then logic and copy/paste processing:

```
k = 10
z = 3
i = 20
for iter = iter to 1000
    Set yourfirstrange = Range("A" & k)
    Set yoursecondrange = Range("B" & z)
    Set yourthirdrange = Range("C" & i)
    ...
    k = k + 1
    z = z + 1
    i = i + 1
next iter
```

Again, be mindful of your range limits and cell number not adequately aligning to each other.

**VLOOKUP**

However, there may be an opportunity to use [Vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) since you simply copy and paste cells matching values across the column ranges.

Below is an example from your innermost for/next (i) loop:

```
'PrezzoFisso.Copy ---> PrezzoPaste.PasteSpecial
Range("D20").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(S3, "I10:J110", 2, FALSE)"
...
Range("D150").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(S133, "I10:J110", 2, FALSE)"


'FornitCerca.Copy ---> NomePaste.PasteSpecial
Range("C20").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(S3, "I10:J110", 1, FALSE)"
...
Range("C150").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(S133, "I10:J110", 1, FALSE)"


'data.Copy ---> DataPaste.PasteSpecial
Range("B20").Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(S3, "I10:J110", 1, FALSE) > 0, R3, 0)"
...
Range("B150").Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(S133, "I10:J110", 1, FALSE) > 0, R133, 0)"
```

Notice S cannot extend past 133 since formula runs cell to cell wise.

**INDEX/MATCH**

Alternatively, you can use [Index/Match](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php) to overcome some Vlookup limitation:

```
'PrezzoFisso.Copy ---> PrezzoPaste.PasteSpecial
Range("D20").Formula = "=INDEX(I10:J110,MATCH(S3,I10:I110,0),2)"

'FornitCerca.Copy ---> NomePaste.PasteSpecial
Range("C20").Formula = "=INDEX(I10:J110,MATCH(S3,I10:I110,0),1)"

'data.Copy ---> DataPaste.PasteSpecial
Range("B20").Formula = "=IF(INDEX(I10:J110,MATCH(S3,I10:I110,0),1)>0, R3, 0)"
```

**DATABASE**

Finally, while on the subject of Cartesian Product, in relational databases, [SQL query joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) are just that: cartesian products on tables. Hence, if you can get your ranges (FornitCerca, PrezzoFisso, FornitVerif, etc.) into distinct tables the related columns can be joined together to create a query into your final resultset. [MS Access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/), Excel's sibling Office product can easily perform this join OR using [Microsoft Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range)