# Macro or other solution in excel to automate interaction of data in two worksheets to come up with a third worksheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vba

I have no idea where to start with this problem (may be due to poor knowledge of terminology). I have two worksheets which I will put up in Google Sheets which I'd like to generate a third worksheet for (also in the same Google Sheets file).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ALQlQhNugUnQzM5NdbFsLX_TlhV6BzT_1TDQKc6hD5I/edit?usp=sharing

I'd like to have information from the Budgeting Groups worksheet be displayed downwards in the Balance worksheet for each company along with their company code in the Company worksheet. Would it be best to write a macro for this interaction or is it possible to do it with formulas? Thanks in advance! Let me know if I wasn't clear.

EDIT: To make it clearer, I'm trying to generate the Balance worksheet from scratch based on information in the Budgeting Groups and Companies worksheet.

Comment: after posting my answer I came to think ... is my VLOOK answer what you are after or are you rather trying to generate a balance sheet from scratch, containing all possible permutations of Budget Groups and Companies ?

Comment: Hi MikeD, thanks for the reply! I'm trying to generate a balance sheet from scratch containing all possible permutations of Budget groups and Companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by [Spioter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279373/spioter) at [Excel vba to create every possible combination of a Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range) which proved immensely helpful! Modified the script to fit my needs and sheet which does not reflect the Google Sheet link in the question. Thank you Spioter!

```
Sub sub_CrossJoin()

Worksheets("Combinations").Range("A4:B2000").ClearContents

Dim rg_Legend As Range
Dim rg_Implementers As Range
Dim rg_RowLegend As Range
Dim rg_RowImplementers As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCol As Range
Dim rg_DestinationCell As Range
Dim int_PriorCombos As Long
Dim int_TotalCombos As Long
Dim int_LegendRowCount As Long
Dim int_ImplementersRowCount As Long
Dim int_ValueRepeats As Long
Dim int_ValueRepeater As Long
Dim int_ValueCycles As Long
Dim int_ValueCycler As Long

int_TotalCombos = 1
int_PriorCombos = 1
int_ValueRowCount = 0
int_ValueCycler = 0
int_ValueRepeater = 0

Set rg_Legend = Worksheets("Legend").Range("A8:A500")
Set rg_Implementers = Worksheets("Implementers").Range("A3:A50")
Set rg_DestinationCol = Worksheets("Combinations").Range("A4")

'Get total combos
int_LegendRowCount = 0
For Each rg_RowLegend In rg_Legend.Cells
    If rg_RowLegend.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    int_LegendRowCount = int_LegendRowCount + 1
Next rg_RowLegend
int_TotalCombos = int_TotalCombos * int_LegendRowCount

int_ImplementersRowCount = 0
For Each rg_RowImplementers In rg_Implementers.Cells
    If rg_RowImplementers.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    int_ImplementersRowCount = int_ImplementersRowCount + 1
Next rg_RowImplementers
int_TotalCombos = int_TotalCombos * int_ImplementersRowCount

int_LegendRowCount = 0
int_ImplementersRowCount = 0

'Calculate the repeats needed for each row value and then populate the destination
int_LegendRowCount = 0
For Each rg_RowLegend In rg_Legend.Cells
    If rg_RowLegend.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    int_LegendRowCount = int_LegendRowCount + 1
Next rg_RowLegend
int_PriorCombos = int_PriorCombos * int_LegendRowCount
int_ValueRepeats = int_TotalCombos / int_PriorCombos

int_ValueCycles = (int_TotalCombos / int_ValueRepeats) / int_LegendRowCount
int_ValueCycler = 0

int_ValueRepeater = 0

Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCol

For int_ValueCycler = 1 To int_ValueCycles
    For Each rg_RowLegend In rg_Legend.Cells
        If rg_RowLegend.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
            For int_ValueRepeater = 1 To int_ValueRepeats
                rg_DestinationCell.Value = rg_RowLegend.Value
                Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCell.Offset(1, 0)
            Next int_ValueRepeater
        Next rg_RowLegend
    Next int_ValueCycler
    Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, 1)

For Each rg_RowImplementers In rg_Implementers.Cells
    If rg_RowImplementers.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    int_ImplementersRowCount = int_ImplementersRowCount + 1
Next rg_RowImplementers
int_PriorCombos = int_PriorCombos * int_ImplementersRowCount
int_ValueRepeats = int_TotalCombos / int_PriorCombos

int_ValueCycles = (int_TotalCombos / int_ValueRepeats) / int_ImplementersRowCount
int_ValueCycler = 0

int_ValueRepeater = 0

Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCol

For int_ValueCycler = 1 To int_ValueCycles
    For Each rg_RowImplementers In rg_Implementers.Cells
        If rg_RowImplementers.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
            For int_ValueRepeater = 1 To int_ValueRepeats
                rg_DestinationCell.Value = rg_RowImplementers.Value
                Set rg_DestinationCell = rg_DestinationCell.Offset(1, 0)
            Next int_ValueRepeater
        Next rg_RowImplementers
    Next int_ValueCycler
    Set rg_DestinationCol = rg_DestinationCol.Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

for companies you have a simple key/value combination, so if in [Balance] you have the company name and want to display the company code from the [Companies] code table you use a simple VLOOKUP, e.g.

```
F2: =vlookup(D2,Companies!A:B,2,false)
```

*(Note: normally it would be reverse ... you have the code and want to expand with the name ... in this case you must reverse the column order in [Companies] as the key column must go in 1st column.)*

The situation is not so clear for the budgeting groups, there may not be a unique key for this list other than a combination of all three colums.