# Excel/VBA/MS Query to create every possible combination of a Range

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have a problem for which I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a spreadsheet with 5 -> 10? columns of data. All of them different, but some columns are related to each other (If A3=1, then B3=A and C3=a). Each column contains 3 -> 6 variations of a parameters and I need to create all the possible combinations of them..

Initial data in columns:

[image]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Kelvin had almost similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range) previously, but that didn't work for me..

Comment: You'll first diagram implies that their are 5 tables and in your description you say there are "5 ->10 column?".  Are their 5 different Tables, with different column counts, and a single **Key Column** in each table or is there a single table with multiple **Key Columns**?

Comment: Hi.
There is 1 table / spreadsheet which contains multiple columns. I'll change the picture.

Comment: How many columns are there and which ones are key columns and which ones are holds the values.  You picture shows 5 columns, key, key, key, value, value.  Is this right?

Comment: That's right for now.. If I just get the point of your code / hint, I can modify it later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using SQL with an cross join. Below is a small example I made and tested. You will have to adapt it to your needs. In my example, test1 and test3 are the column names, in the first row of `sheet1`.

```
Sub SQLCombineExample()
    Dim con
    Dim rs
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
           "DriverId=790;" & _
           "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rs = con.Execute("select distinct a.[test1], b.[test3] from [Sheet1$] as a , [Sheet1$] as b ")
    Range("f1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You didn't mention which library to reference.  I tried the latest ActiveX Dataobjects library and got the an error.  Too few parameters.

Comment: @ThomasInzina: right:  I used Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.

Comment: Okay I got it. Awesome answer but you left out all the details.  You should explain that test1 and test3 refer to column names and change your query to **select distinct a.* , b.test3 from [Sheet1$] as a , [Sheet1$] as b**.

Comment: Damn, you don't even have to save the workbook.  That's tight. I'm adding this to my arsenal!

Comment: @ThomasInzina: with this trick you can even join different sheets and make update queries 8-)

Answer (score 0):

From what i see in your pictures, the only item which can change combination is the one in column 4:
(1 ; A ; a ; item4 ; #¤), (2 ; B ; b ; item4 ; &#¤) and (3 ; C ; c ; item4 ; ¤%&)

If this is indeed what your are trying to do the following code should work:

```
Sub Combination()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    For k = 0 To 2 'loop through (1 A a #¤), (2 B b &#¤) and (3 C c ¤%&)

        j = 3 'column 4 items

        For i = 0 To 6 Step (3) 'loop 3 by 3 (output starts in row 10)

                Cells(10 + k + i, 1) = Cells(3 + k, 1)
                Cells(10 + k + i, 2) = Cells(3 + k, 2)
                Cells(10 + k + i, 3) = Cells(3 + k, 3)
                Cells(10 + k + i, 5) = Cells(3 + k, 5)

                Cells(10 + k + i, 4) = Cells(j, 4)

        j = j + 1

        Next i

    Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyAllCombinationsToRange()

    Dim arSource
    Dim arResult

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, combinationCount As Long, counter As Long

    arSource = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value

    combinationCount = UBound(arSource, 2) * UBound(arSource, 2)
    ReDim arResult(4, combinationCount - 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arSource, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arSource, 1)

            arResult(0, counter) = arSource(i, 1)
            arResult(1, counter) = arSource(i, 2)
            arResult(2, counter) = arSource(i, 3)
            arResult(3, counter) = arSource(i, 4)
            arResult(4, counter) = arSource(j, 5)
            counter = counter + 1
        Next
    Next

    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arResult, 2), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arResult)

End Sub
```

**Example**

[image]