# For without next in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get all possible combinations with a kind of VBA macro presented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693789/1992004, but get an error `For without Next`. I compared the source from another thread with mine, but don't found such difference, which could cause this error.

Do you see, what causes this error? - please point me to. My Code follows.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim l As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, q As Long, r As Long, s As Long, t As Long, u As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Range("L2").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 18

    For l = 1 To 1: For m = 1 To 2
    For n = 1 To 2: For o = 1 To 18
    For p = 1 To 15: For q = 1 To 10
    For r = 1 To 10: For s = 1 To 17
    For t = 1 To 3: For u = 1 To 3
        Range("L" & lastrow).Value = Range("A" & l).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("B" & m).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("C" & n).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("D" & o).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("E" & p).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("F" & q).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("G" & r).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("H" & s).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("I" & t).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("J" & u).Value
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
    Next: Next
    Next: Next

    Range("L1").Value = CountComb
    Range("L3").Value = Now

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You have 10 for loops and only 4 Next statements, you are missing 6... In other words just write 3 new lines with Next: Next

Comment: Bad code formatting aside, I see 10 For's and 4 Next's.

Comment: As per Brian's comment.  But any deeper nesting than 3 levels and something is very smelly in the code and in need of a refactor.

Comment: One of those error messages which does what it says on the tin.

Comment: The thing about indenting properly and not put ting multiple statements on a single line is that with nesting, if you don't end up with a balanced > shape you know immediately something is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the comments above explain your problem, but this is what your code would look like with proper indenting AND the missing "next" statements:

```
For l = 1 To 1
    For m = 1 To 2
        For n = 1 To 2
            For o = 1 To 18
                For p = 1 To 15
                    For q = 1 To 10
                        For r = 1 To 10
                            For s = 1 To 17
                                For t = 1 To 3
                                    For u = 1 To 3
                                        Range("L" & lastrow).Value = Range("A" & l).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("B" & m).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("C" & n).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("D" & o).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("E" & p).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("F" & q).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("G" & r).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("H" & s).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("I" & t).Value & "/" & _
                                                                     Range("J" & u).Value
                                        lastrow = lastrow + 1
                                        CountComb = CountComb + 1
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

At the very least, it would have made it immediately obvious where your code was failing.

Comment: Perhaps complete the Nexts with the appropriate control variables aswell.

Comment: I used Notepad++ - made it fairly easy to reformat.  That's what I'm going to use in the future when reformatting other people's code, like poorly formatted Java.  @QHarr I personally would use the counters in the next statement, but believe it or not, the code runs faster without them according to benchmarks.

Comment: I can't argue with that but I would be surprised if it made a noticeable difference. Would be interested in reading anything about it though. For me it makes debugging easier.  I can instantly see where I am at.

Comment: There was a post about that very topic in RetroComputing on Stack Exchange: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6448/in-ms-basic-why-is-next-faster-than-next-i

Comment: Thank you. It still fires an error, but i think its because the amount of calculated rows is higher then an excel table could contain. Do you see any fast possibility to calculate the amount of rows befor filling them?