Map "numbers" to "rows"
Suppose we have the following data:

I want to put the numbers side-by-side with the rows:

What I understand is the code should recursively do this per cell in the "numbers" list.
The first number gets mapped to all the rows in the "rows" data, then the same for the next on the list and so on.

Why do you think that the code should be able to recursively do it? What about two loops? And what did you try? Any code you can provide where you have trouble?

You could also use PowerQuery for this.

Already answered here, code that angled arbitrary columns of inputs, out is a Cartesian join https://stackoverflow.com/a/13385162/1279373

This question is similar to: Excel vba to create every possible combination of a Range. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

How to perform a cross join in power query
Assume you have your tables:

Load them into Power query

Add a custom Column

Expand your new custom Column

Filter the Column Custom.R1

Choose close and load!



This formula returns the values in range G2:J7:
=LET(r1st, $A$2:$A$4,
     r2nd, $C$2:$E$3,
     cntA, ROWS(r1st),
     cntB, ROWS(r2nd),
     lstA, INDEX(r1st, INT(SEQUENCE(cntA*cntB,,1,1/cntB))),
     lstB, CHOOSEROWS(r2nd,MOD(SEQUENCE(cntA*cntB,,0),cntB)+1),
     HSTACK(lstA,lstB))

I gave the range a custom number format of 0;-0;;@ otherwise the A, C row ends with a 0.
I used this answer by @ScottCraner to work most of it out:
Formula to create a cartesian product from two data sets in a spilled range
Edit:
Without the custom number format.  Also updated so will extend if range is altered.
=LET(r1st, $A$2:$A$4,
     r2nd, IF($C$2:$E$3=0,"",$C$2:$E$3),
     cntA, ROWS(r1st),
     cntB, ROWS(r2nd),
     lstA, INDEX(r1st, INT(SEQUENCE(cntA*cntB,,1,1/cntB))),
     lstB, CHOOSEROWS(r2nd,MOD(SEQUENCE(cntA*cntB,,0),cntB)+1),
     HSTACK(lstA,lstB))



You can use Unpivot2 macro.
First, prepare the source table. Copy numbers to new the location, then copy Rows above with transposing (select C1:E2, Copy, select G3, Paste Special):

Then select the table and activate the pivot cell:

Run the macro and get the result:


In-place expansion may be possible with VBA, but if it is fine to place the results in a different area, you could try this:

With Microsoft 365
A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1) to dynamically include non-empty rows

=LET(
    nums, A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1),
    rows_, C2:E3,
    num_row, LAMBDA(acc, num,
        VSTACK(
            acc,
            HSTACK(
                EXPAND(num, ROWS(rows_), , num),
                IF(ISBLANK(rows_), "", rows_)
            )
        )
    ),
    header, EXPAND("", , 1 + COLUMNS(rows_), ""),
    REDUCE(header, nums, num_row)
)


